# Woocommerce - How can I achieve a greyed-out overlay affect on thumbnails?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress/Woocommerce theme I'me building with products. And when products are out of stock, I've coded a p tag that displays 'Out of stock' below the product thumbnail using the following code:

```
function envy_stock_catalog() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            return;
        } else {
        echo '<div class="out-of-stock" >' . __( 'out of stock', 'envy' ) . '</div>';
                add_action('init','remove_loop_button');
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'envy_stock_catalog' );
```

I also want the product thumbnail to have a greyed-out effect. Where the product image is still visible but there's a greyed-out transparent overlay.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this? All suggestions are welcome and thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have assumed your code will be something like this:**

```
<div class="product">
    <img src="http://academy.bindtuning.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/wplogoblue-notext-rgb.png" height="300" width="300" />
    <p class="out-of-stock">Out of Stock</p>
</div>
```

*Note: I used jQuery to add a new `<div class='img-overlay'></div>` before `img` because CSS pseudo selectors are not fully supported by older browsers*

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  
// Adding a new <div> img-overlay before img present inside product
  
$("<div class='img-overlay'></div>").insertBefore(".product img");
});
```

```css
.product{
  position:relative;
  width:300px; /* Setting this property is mandatory since .img-overlay inherits width from here */
  height:300px; /* Setting this property is mandatory since .img-overlay inherits height from here */
}

.out-of-stock{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  background:#fff;
  color:#373737;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:13px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100; /* Used it to push .out-of-stock above .img-overlay*/
}

.product .img-overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:rgba(90,90,90,0.5); /* Play with 0.5 to set the transparency of overlay div*/
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
 <img src="http://academy.bindtuning.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/wplogoblue-notext-rgb.png" height="300" width="300" />
<p class="out-of-stock">
Out of Stock
</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This looks brilliant! Can wait to try it. Can I just confirm what files in should I add the code to? Functions.php? I know the CSS goes in my stylesheet but I'm not 100% on the jQuery and HTML

Comment: You need to understand this in order to implement it or post your HTML markup so that i can updated the answer based on that.

Comment: I don't understand... I'm asking for files names

Comment: I was saying that these CSS classes and HTML markup are just an example. Copy pasting this will not work on your site so you need to understand the working and implement it or you need to update the question with your own HTML and CSS code so that i can update my answer based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following css to your theme's custom.css file

```
.woocommerce span.soldout, .woocommerce-page span.soldout {
    //Add overlay image url or effect
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you, but I was a grey overlay on the thumbnail, not the p tag.

Comment: You can check your html tag and do like this .out-of-stock img {add overaly image url}

Comment: It's woocommerce products so theres a lot of them

Comment: I understand your thinking, But this is the easiest way to do with CSS in woo commerce style or theme style and it does not depend how much products u have. Kindly try this and tell me if this makes any issue to tell me, I will give u an another solution.